# Getting NotImplementedError: While Importing ARMA

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series

This is the error massage got
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPZbu.png)

Of Course There's a way to import it....When Trying use (statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA) it gives me only ARIMA..Is it moved from statsmodels to another Library or what And how should i import it?